# Populating store with records parameter from proxy

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

In my store I am calling **load** on a store. It is hitting the server and getting a bunch of data, however my data is not in the records object.

Instead the data I want is in the **operation.response** object.

```
store.load({
    params: postBody,
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        if (success) {
            console.info('seccuess')

            var decoded = Ext.decode(operation.response.responseText);

            if(decoded.success && decoded.result.length > 0){
                var results = decoded.result; //results are in record array here!!!

            }
        }
    }
});
```

The records object is returning something that is not what I want.

All the records seem to be in the **operation.response** object (see **results** variable). I didn't write this code so I can't explain the reasoning behind this.

*Bottom line* : How do I inject/set/put these results into the store?

Is there something like this :

```
this.setData(results)
```

that I can call in the callback object? The proxy magic going on behind the scenes is trying to apply the records object onto my grid.

Comment: I think i have partially solved this. If I use store.add(results) on an outside reference to the store it works, however it is still adding this extra row at the start which is the records object which I do not want

Comment: Have you checked that `proxy.reader.rootProperty` is set to the correct value? EDIT: In ExtJS 4, it was called `proxy.reader.root`...

Comment: yes i think that will solve my problem better. i will give it a try